# New roadbike. Poor cassette quality control?

Tags: shimano, cassette

I've just bought a new ROSE PRO SL 105 roadbike and took it for a spin. At first, i noticed a little **clicking sound in the rear cassette**. I thought that it only might need some time for the chain to sit properly. When I took a closer look at the cassette, I've noticed that **some of the teeth look a little too sharp**, unlike the others.

[image: rear cassette]

Is this something I should be worried of? It seems to me like a failure of the quality control. The rear cassette is a Shimano 105 CS-5800 11-speed.

If so, I will contact the support for the warranty claim. Do you have any experience how they will approach this problem? Rose is a manufacturer and also a direct bike seller like Canyon, so they have no retail stores.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I agree with the other posters that asymetrical teeth shapes are normal, yours" appear more extreme on the left side circled teeth than the single on the right side.  I would suggest returning to the dealer, explain your concern about the clicking noise. While they are evaluating your bike look at others in the shop and see if the cassettes look similar.

Comment: Had the same issue on a Rose X-Lite Four (Ultegra R8000 group). It went away over 1000km or so. It was also visible; on some teeth the chain didn’t slide smoothly onto the cogs (even though it was perfectly aligned). I think some of the shifting aids on the cogs are formed too aggressively when new. After a couple hundred km they are worn down far enough to allow completely smooth operation. I don’t think this is a real issue and not a failure of quality control. The noise is a bit annoying though.

Comment: Not directly related, but that chain looks very clean while that cassette shows a surprising amount of dirt already.

Comment: @Criggie It's a result of the factory lube remaining still on the cassette. It is somewhat sticky and attracts a lot of dirt. I've cleaned the chain but not the cassette. Good point to do so.

Comment: When you drop the wheel out to clean the cassette, check the cassette model number for my curiosity’s sake ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My CS-5800 105 cassette [image: My CS-5800] looks the same and being curious I have checked at the store and they all look exactly same so it must be indeed a special tooling to help with gear changes.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 11):

There does not appear to be anything wrong with the cassette. Shimano helpfully put some nice clear pictures of individual sprockets on the product page for the CS-58000 cassette.

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/CS-5800.html

You can easily see that the smaller sprockets have some 'chisel' shaped teeth.

Clicking at the rear derailleur usually indicates slightly miss-adjusted indexing which is quite plausible on a new bike. Check for that first.

Comment: Usually some turning of the barrel adjuster on the rear derailleur should sort that out. (half a turn left or right might do)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not specifically familiar with Shimano 105 but odd-shaped teeth on cassettes and chain-rings are usually designed that way to aid shifting. It's also hard to imagine a manufacturing process that could go wrong in a way that would produce the shapes you show.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out :). That's what I thought at first, but I have not owned a cassette like this before.

Comment: @MatyášSkalický This technology is called [Hyperglide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperglide), and it's what the HG stands for on the chain links :-)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness I’ve quoted my existing answer below, but having gone through it all I’m satisfied that you have a new, updated tooth profile and all is ok. Thanks to David Richerby for linking to the R7000 cassette which has these circled features. I then was able to look at an Ultegra R8000 equipped bike yesterday and saw them also, not sure which cassette but it was new and shared these features.

Somehow your cassette has updated features, if it’s not a new R7000 cassette snuck into Rose’s inventory, perhaps selected new-design cogs have been included by Shimano and shipped out ‘early’.

No doubt in a few months these teeth profiles will be *de rigeur* and these questions won’t take (me) so much faff to answer ;)

> The pair you’ve circled on the right are extra tall teeth that are a newer feature of Shimano cassettes that look normal.
>
> The other three smaller red circles look to me like there is material missing from those teeth. That seems abnormal to me. I have looked on a 5800 cassette and include a stock photo below, I can’t see evidence of this missing material in either. Most teeth in the smallest two cogs  are roughly symmetrical.
>
> I would therefore follow up with Rose for advice if on the cassette you do have missing material (and it’s not just my interpretation of your photograph)
>
> [image: 105 5800 cassette]
>
> Update:
>
> I’ve included an extract of the photo in Argenti’s helpful link, of both 12 and 11 tooth 5800 cogs below.
>
> The profile of each of the teeth goes smoothly from the base of each trough to the full height of the tooth in a smooth curve, although the curve can be different on each side of various teeth, it is one smooth, continuous curve.
>
> What I see in your photograph is that the three small red circles highlight teeth with a ‘step’ part way up the right side of a tooth, that then curves up to the top of the tooth. I think it’s abnormal for that profile to be across the full depth of the tooth
>
> If this isn’t the case then I’m misreading the photograph.
>
> [image: 12 and 11 cog from CS-5800]

Comment: *The other three smaller red circles look to me like there is material missing from those teeth.* And they're all machined perfectly smooth, rounded, and appear identical.  There's no way those are anything but deliberate.

Comment: @Andrew that would be great for OP. It’s not something I’ve seen, can you explain why it is machined like that and provide a photo of a new casssette with the same features?

Comment: I agree that the photo in the question has a tooth profile on the second-smallest cog that doesn't match the Shimano product photos.

Comment: But the [CS-R7000 cassette](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/CS-R7000.html) does have some similar shaped teeth. Perhaps the asker has one of those, or a cassette made from a mixture of parts?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Or the cassette was improved, changing the tooth profile just a bit, and Shimano didn't bother to update the photo on their website.

Comment: @David yes! Good spot, seems so logical now, slightly out-of-the box thinking. I’m much more satisfied to have something to point at and say it’s designed like that, than assuming so. Even if it’s same answer (all ok) and OP seems happy

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that's an updated cassette to allow for greater chainline angle when in the smallest cogs. Newer bikes, mostly disc road, move the cassette out 2.5mm from before. Shimano is fanatical about little details.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the change for stuck links in the chain. When I bought mine this was an issue. Replacing the links resolved the clicking.

Comment: Be aware that modern Shimano chains are "all-or-nothing". After the initial sizing and installation of the master link pin, none of the pins or links are replaceable, and the only (official) way to fix a broken link or pin is to replace the chain in its entirety.

Comment: This is one reason why you buy Wippermann instead of Shimano :)